# Creating more than 1 different objects in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

Well, I have been learning openGL with this tutorial: opengl-tutorial.org.
That tutorial do not explain how do the shaders works. I mean, is the vertex shader readed before the fragment shader?

Ok talking about the question, I want to create two objects for practice, one box (3D Square with a texture) and a pyramid (3D Triangle with a texture), I don't know how to do it, I know how to draw it with C++/OpenGl but talking about the GLSL.... Do I need to create another program? How can I do that?

(OpenGL 3.3)

Comment: Please go through the famous webgl lessons: http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?p=28  or http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/

Comment: I need tutorials of opengl3.3, nehe is not opengl3.3 I think, the same website published a post about a opengl3.3 oriented tutorial on the website opengl-tutorial.org ...

Comment: Already changed the comment...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenGL does not maintain "objects" in such a way as you seem to assume (the term object is used to refer to "something" internal that OpenGL uses and that you can refer to via an identifier. A vertex buffer, a texture, or a shader are all examples of "objects"). OpenGL is not a [scenegraph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scenegraph).

You need to create the vertex data for each of your objects in your application (or load that data from a file) and to provide OpenGL with that by feeding a buffer object with that data.

Then you tell OpenGL to draw a number of vertices from that buffer. OpenGL does not care what that data is or how to draw it. It will only do exactly what you tell it to do. If you tell it "take this block of data that contains vertex coordinates, and now draw 5 triangles", then it will just do that.

Comment: Thanks! So, starting from that, in the side of the programs (glCreateProgram())? How can I handle two textures with GLSL?

Comment: You'd do that in exactly the same way as you do with a single texture, except you do everything (create/bind texture) twice on the application side and have two samplers instead of one in GLSL.

Comment: One more question:
color = texture(thesampler,theUv).rgb; (Fragment shader)
I created 2 samplers, so... How can GLSL knows what texture should draw?

Comment: Thank you very much for your speed answer! I really love to program in openGl. :) Thanks